# Scala can't prove path dependent types are equal though it should be clear?

Tags: scala

```
trait A {
  type Foo
  def bar: Foo = B(this).bar
}

case class B(a: A) extends A {
  type Foo = a.Foo
}
```

I realize that this example is a bit contrived, but shouldn't this compile? I get the following error:

```
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : _5.a.Foo where val _5: B
 required: A.this.Foo
             def bar: Foo = B(this).bar
```

I realize my example is weird, but it should be clear that the Foos are the same, no? Because "this" is the path defining Foo!

Do I just have to cast it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works just fine:

```
trait A {
  type Foo
  def bar: Foo = B(this).bar
}

def B(a: A): A { type Foo = a.Foo } = new A {
  type Foo = a.Foo
}
```

So it looks like the compiler just isn't being smart enough about tracking what your `B`'s `Foo` is. Maybe you could convince someone on the compiler team that this is a bug, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this work is to give an initial type to Foo. It seems the type inference without this goes into inferring a complex type that is incompatible with what you expect.

(Note: If someone knows more about the details, I would love to also learn more about this.)

```
trait A {
  type Foo = Int
  def bar: Foo = B(this).bar
}

case class B(a: A) extends A {
  override type Foo = a.Foo
}
```

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose, though…